# Is it necessary to set NetworkCredential domain?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

Is it necessary to set networkCredential domain while accessing a web service?

```
var service = new service1.SoapEx();
service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password", "domain");
```

or i can do:

```
 var service = new service1.SoapEx();
 service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not necessary as the [NetworkCredential](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkcredential(v=vs.110).aspx) class features a constructor just like your second example.  Keep in mind though that the password param only accepts SecureString, not String.

Comment: Ok, Thank you. You can tell me if not setting a domain can cause any problem?

Comment: Not that I'm aware.  I think the only issue you might encounter is if you try to access a web service that is hosted in domain you may encounter issues (but shouldn't, unless that web service isn't smart enough to fill in the domain, or you're working in a forest with multiple domains)