# While Downloading the excel file from SharePoint getting The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden. in windows application c#

Tags: c#, windows, sharepoint

I want to download the excel from SharePoint and I have read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51845724/download-excel-files-from-sharepoint-site-to-local-system-using-c-sharp) for achieve my requirement and also I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33736441/is-it-necessary-to-set-networkcredential-domain) for NetworkCredential domain once I get the basic knowledge on this task I have written the code and at the runtime I got

> The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

for this I have read this [post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/80961/the-remote-server-returned-an-error-403-forbidden) for understanding the error and I have changed the code but not working well.

This is my code:

```
public void DownloadFilesFromSharePoint(string siteUrl, string siteFolderPath, string localTempLocation)
        {

            //string tempLocation = @"c:\Downloads\Sharepoint\";
            string tempLocation = localTempLocation;
            System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(tempLocation);
            foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles())
            {
                file.Delete();
            }
            ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(siteUrl);

            SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in "Welcome@1045".ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);

            //"smtp.office365.com"; // "domain-com.mail.protection.outlook.com"; // "smtp.office365.com";//.secureserver.net";// "relay -hosting.secureserver.net"; //smtp-mail.outlook.com
            //ctx.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("kumar@xxxx.com", "Welcome@1045", "smtp.office365.com");
            ctx.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("kumar@xxxx.com", passWord);

            FileCollection files = ctx.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(siteFolderPath).Files;

            ctx.Load(files);
            if (ctx.HasPendingRequest)
            {
                ctx.ExecuteQuery(); //The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.(here I'm getting the error)
            }

            foreach (File file in files)
            {
                FileInformation fileInfo = File.OpenBinaryDirect(ctx, file.ServerRelativeUrl);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();

                var filePath = localTempLocation + "\\" + file.Name;
                System.IO.FileStream fileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(filePath, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite, System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite);

                fileInfo.Stream.CopyTo(fileStream);

            }
        }
```

And I'm calling this method like this:

```
string url ="https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/my_files/all%20Files";
string folderpath = "https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/my_files/all%20Files/Task%20Management";
string templocation = @"c:\Downloads\Sharepoint\";
DownloadFilesFromSharePoint(url, folderpath, templocation);
```

And used this `Microsoft.SharePoint.client` dll.

Using Namespaces:

```
using System;
using Form = System.Windows.Forms.Form;
using System.Security;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using File = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File;
```

Where I did the mistake and how to achieve this?

Comment: When searching web check dates of postings.  Old postings may not solve issues.  don't use credentials with Username and password, they usually do not work with new version of windows due to security changes.  Try removing the credentials which will use the default credentials of the logon user.

Comment: Hi @jdweng thanks for your comment and  as per your comment  `don't use credentials with Username and password` I have changed my code like this `ClientContext context = new ClientContext(new Uri(url)); context.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default; context.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials; Web w = context.Web; context.Load(w, website => website.Webs,website => website.Title);context.ExecuteQuery(); //The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.` after this code getting the same error
if you post an answer on this issue it would be appreciate.

Comment: I want to check if the credentials are the issue or something else.  Try using a browser and manually download files.  If this works than try you c# code again.  If c# works then we know a cookies was established to make c# code work.  We will also know that you have the permission to do the download.

Comment: @jdweng I have downloaded manually and file was downloaded and spoke with my team they given full access to me and again I have run this code and put the break point getting same error.

Comment: There are only two reasons for failure 1) siteFolderPath is not valid 2) You are an admin and you are running inside VS.  You need to start VS by right click VS and select Run As Admin.

Comment: @jdweng after review your latest comment I have run the vs as admin and run the code and getting the same error and next I have given the `FolderPath` correctly for reference [https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/my_files/all%20Files](https://i.postimg.cc/yYQFSMZ0/sharepoint-1.png) and [https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/my_files/all%20Files/Task%20Management](https://i.postimg.cc/XvvcPV6H/sharepoint-2.png) this url links are getting the correct path of the folders.

Comment: When you ran in browser did you use HTTP or HTTPS? When you did manually was URL exactly the same as in c#?

Comment: I'm running in browser using  HTTPS only and in c# also using same ex:- `https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/my_files/all%20Files`.

Note :- even I'm passing `http`  in browser  `http://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/my_files/all%20Files` it is taking `. `https` https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/my_files/all%20Files`.

Comment: Error is probably caused by the http header missing or wrong parameter. Possibly a cookie The best way of finding is to a use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  HTTPS the headers are encrypted.  So just for a test make http and capture both a manual and c# request.  Then compare the two captures.

Comment: sure will do and update here and thanks for  your patience with me .

Comment: @jdweng I have tried as per your latest comment answer and the result is same not working well  it's look like unsolved answer.

Comment: The sniffer showed exactly the same HTTP headers in the results?  Was a cookie used?

Comment: The sniffer showed exactly the same HTTP headers in the results ==> yes ,sniffer showed exactly the same HTTP headers in the results and Was a cookie used ==> no cookies are used.

Comment: If message is exactly the same (including IP and port) in sniffer, than it has to be the credentials.  Are you running inside VS or outside?  The only difference would be if you are inside VS and not running as an Admin.

Comment: Actually I have changed the line of code in my existing code that is `ctx.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("kumar@xxxx.com", passWord);` instead of this`ctx. Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("kumar@xxxx.com", passWord);` after changed this line of code I'm getting the following error `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequestException: 'Cannot contact site at the specified URL https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/my_files/all%20Files. There is no Web named "/sites/my_files/all Files/_vti_bin/sites.asmx".` at this location of code
if (ctx.HasPendingRequest) { ctx.ExecuteQuery(); }

Comment: Why this error is coming can you suggest me on this ?

Comment: Maybe it is a proxy issue? I think the last change you made is wrong.  I know there are ways to tell that a connection is coming from an application verses manually, but not sure how it is done.  Is server using same password server as you machine?  Then you should be using default credentials.  What credentials is the webbrowser using?

Comment: `(Is server using same password server as you machine?)` actually this is the shared document and anyone can use excel file if they have proper credentials right now 6 members have the rights to access this folder. `(What credentials is the web browser using?)` we can't judge because this is shared folder in share point right now I'm giving my credentials in logic `username and password`(and they given full access to my account).

Comment: 1. (Is server using same password server as you machine?) for this ==> Yes

2. (What credentials is the web browser using?) for this ==> right now my credentials using in logic 

Note : for this 2 questions, answer is (using my credentials only).

Comment: The real question should be what protocol is being used for the download.  Network Credentials and error 403 are used with HTTP or FTP not Windows File Transfer.

Comment: Hi @jdweng finally I achieved this error and thanks for your help and patience with me really I appreciate you.

Comment: @Kumar: I take it you were able to solve this issue. Could you post your solution? I am facing the same error.